# Best way to return a transform iterator range

Tags: c++, dictionary, iterator, iterator-range

Let's say I want to write a simple function `keys` that takes in a `std::map` and returns an `iterator_range` that provides the keys of the map. How would I do it?

```
template<typename A, typename B>
Range<A> keys(const std::map<A, B> & m) { ??? }
```

I want to apply the same pattern to various other containers, but I think this is a good prototypical example.

**Edit:** I'm guessing I need something in the realm of Boost's `range_adapter`s and/or `transform_iterator`s but I'm not familiar enough with them to apply them here.

Comment: Are you talking about [boost's `iterator_range`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/utilities/iterator_range.html)?

Comment: Yes, but I'm not attached to it.

Comment: .... something like the [`boost::adaptors::keys`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors/reference/map_keys.html) function?

Comment: @dyp: The best things in life have already been done. ;) Thanks. I'll have to look at the implementation and see if that helps me repeat the pattern elsewhere.

Comment: @3noch - have you find a solution? if yes, answer your own question so the community will learn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This particular need is met with `boost::adapters::keys`. More generally, `boost::range` allows you to design your own adapters, but it's somewhat involved. So unless you're designing a new library, you might be able to get away with `transformed`.

If you need the result of your range back into a container, you can write a simple `collect` function which will "collect" the result of a `boost::range` pipeline.

```
template<typename Output, typename SinglePassRange>
Output collect(const SinglePassRange & rng)
{
    Output r;
    boost::range::copy(rng, std::inserter(r, boost::begin(r)));
    return r;
}
```

Now you can easily whip up some little functions and

- `collect<vector<int>>(numbers | filtered(odd))`
- `collect<vector<int>>(numbers | transformed(doubled))`
- `collect<vector<K>>(myMap | transformed(keyOf))`